# centering content with \oddsidemargin

Tags: margins, tabularx

I have a big document only composed of tabular or tabularx (product specifications) and I would like to center them in the whole document. Those tabular are considerable, most of them use the full width availiable (in this case it's a basic portrait A4 paper), so 21cm.

*Examples:*

```
\begin{tabularx}{21cm}{X X X}
...
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{15cm}{X X X}
...
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{20.5cm}{X X X}
...
\end{tabularx}
```

When I started making all the tabulars, I realize that a tabular have a kind of margin around it and as the space is precious to me, I decide to remove all margins in the document. To do that, I use the command `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.22in}` ([found here](https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins)) which shift the whole content of the document a little bit to the left to compensate the tabular left margin.

But now, when I try to center all tabulars (because some of them are smaller) in the page using `\centering` or any other centering technic, there are not centered. They are in fact but with an additional 1.22in on the left, which is exactly the length specified in `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.22in}`.

If I comment `%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.22in}`, most of my tabulars exceed on the right and are then truncated (so some end of text are not displayed)

**So I have severals questions at this point :**

- Did I wrongly remove the margin of my document ? Because here I am not removing them but compensating them in fact.
- Is it possible to do without `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.22in}` to be able to use the `\centering` command in the correct way ?
- If not, is there any way to disable or set to 0 the right margin (and not the padding like in HTML) of a tabular ?

Thanks,

*Note 1* : I did not specified any `\textwidth`, all the original with `\documentclass{article}[10pt,a4paper,sans]`

*Note 2* : I use those commands to remove margins and other stuff :

```
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.4in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.22in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0in}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0in}
```

Comment: it is very hard to guess what you have done or what the outcome is, please post a single small but complete document that shows the problem, so people can debug it.

Comment: setting the margin to be negative is rather weird (and quite hard to define what centering should then mean, but without a test document it is impossible to guess, in particular the main length affecting `\centering` is `\textwidth` and you have given no information about that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not specified any `\textwidth` in the whole document, should I ?

Comment: well since in most classes it will default to a value suitable for US letter paper then probably you need to change that  but  as you have just posted disjointed fragments it is really impossible to say. The images you have added to not clarify the question at all, you need to post a test document and the output _from that document_

Comment: also you almost certainly don't want the `table` environment (and certainly not `\begin{table}[h]`) if your document just consists of tabulars, that makes it impossible to set the tables at all, so all the tables will be held in memory until the end of the document and then dumped as an emergency fallback output.

Comment: the fact that the table goes off the left off the page is the expected outcome if you set a negative left margin.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}[10pt,a4paper,sans]` the optional argument in that position does nothing so you are setting this for us letter paper but viewing it on A4

Comment: I post a fragment of the code source. So do I have to do a `\begin{table}[h]` for each tabular then or is the problem that you describe will be persistent ? Yeah that's right, it's kind of my fault, tex do what I ask him so I am the only one to blame.

Comment: I may don't understand, so in fact the `\documentclass{article}[10pt,a4paper,sans]` is not usefull ? What should be the good configuration then ?

Comment: you have the option in the wrong place, to specify 10pt a4 it should be `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A skeleton for a document with horizontally centered tables that might occupy the full text width would be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=0mm, % Remove left and right margin
  % Set vertical margin or whatever
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No indentation of first lines in paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex minus 1ex plus 4ex}% Vertical space between paragraphs

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{21cm}{X X X}
  ...
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{15cm}{X X X}
  ...
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{20.5cm}{X X X}
  ...
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The empty lines between the environments `tabularx` are important. Then each table is set inside a new paragraph. The space between these paragraphs can be configured by `\parskip`, see the preamble.

Comment: That was the perfect answer, It worked for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The markup for the table was over complicated and forcing many over full boxes, this version has no over or under full box warnings and so centres on the page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.4in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0in}
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}

\begin{document}
\centering



\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\large\textbf{Neurologique}&
\large\textbf{Ventilatoire}&
\large\textbf{Circulatoire}\\
\begin{tabular}{l r l}
\multirowcell{3}{Pupilles\\\underline{NRS}}&\underline{n}ormales&Oui / Non\\
&\underline{r}\'{e}actives&Oui / Non\\
&\underline{s}ym\'{e}triques&Oui / Non\\
\multirowcell{2}{Rep\`{e}re\\\underline{OST}}&\underline{t}emps&Oui / Non\\
&\underline{e}space&Oui / Non\\
\multirowcell{6}{Motricit\'{e}\\\underline{MS4M}}&main G&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
&main D&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
&pied G&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
&pied D&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
&doigt Sym.&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
&pieds Sym.&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l r l}
Chaleur&temp\'{e}rature&\raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{1cm}{0.1mm}}\raisebox{4px}{\begin{math}\circ\end{math}}C\\
Saturation&SpO\textsubscript{2} (\begin{math}\geq\end{math}94)&\raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{1cm}{0.1mm}}\%\\
\multirowcell{3}{Fr\'{e}quence\\Ventilatoire\\\underline{ARS}}&\underline{a}mple&Oui / Non\\
&\underline{r}\'{e}guli\`{e}re&Oui / Non\\
&\underline{s}ym\'{e}trique&Oui / Non\\
\multirowcell{3}{Respiration\\\underline{A--Normale}}&gasps&Oui / Non\\
&sifflements&Oui / Non\\
&ronflements&Oui / Non\\
Fr\'{e}quence&respiratoire&\raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{8mm}{0.1mm}}mpm\\
\textbf{Enfant}&\textbf{Ado}&\textbf{Adulte}\\
30--60&30--20&20--12
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l r l}
TRC&recoloration&\raisebox{1px}{\begin{math}<\end{math}}3s / \begin{math}\geq\end{math}3s\\
\multirowcell{4}{Tension\\art\'{e}rielle}&mesure sur&Hum. / Carot.\\
&gauche&\raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{8mm}{0.1mm}} / \raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{8mm}{0.1mm}}\\
&droite&\raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{8mm}{0.1mm}} / \raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{8mm}{0.1mm}}\\
&r\'{e}f\'{e}rence&\raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{8mm}{0.1mm}} / \raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{8mm}{0.1mm}}\\
\multirowcell{3}{Pouls\\\underline{RBFS}}&\underline{r}\'{e}gulier&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
&\underline{b}ien \underline{f}rapp\'{e}&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
&\underline{s}ym\'{e}trique&OK\,/\,\begin{math}\approx\end{math}\,/\,KO\\
Fr\'{e}quence&cardiaque&\raisebox{-0.4mm}{\rule{13mm}{0.1mm}}bpm\\
\textbf{Enfant}&\textbf{Ado}&\textbf{Adulte}\\
100--160&70--140&60--100
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{tabular}{r l c c l c c l c c l}
\multicolumn{11}{c}{\large{\textbf{Bilan d'examen compl\'{e}mentaire}}}\\
Refus de:&s'allonger / s'assoir&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Sueurs&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Pacemaker&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Veines apparentes\\
\'Etat:&anxieux(e) / stress\'{e}(e)&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&P\^{a}leurs&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Muqueuses&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Extr\^{e}mit\'{e}s froides\\
Sensation:&froid / chaud&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Cloques&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Maux de t\^{e}te&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Fatigue g\'{e}n\'{e}ralis\'{e}e\\
Sensation:&soif / transpiration&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Angoisse&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Conjonctivite&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Insectes implant\'{e}es\\
Sensation:&de vide / d\'{e}s\'{e}quilibre&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Cyanoses&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&L\`{e}vres jers\'{e}es&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Mycoses aux ongles\\
Difficult\'{e}s \`{a}:&parler / bouger&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Marbrures&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Fourmillements&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Odeur forte d'alcool\\
Paralysie:&gauche / droite&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Somnolent&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Traces de piq\^{u}res&\quad\,\quad&\framebox(10, 10)&Envie de vomissements\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```